# Is there a symbol that is \longto minus the tip

Tags: symbols

I wonder if there is a horizontal line math symbol that

- has the same length as `\longto`, `\longmapsto`, etc
  but does not contain any arrow tips, and
- is a `\mathrel`?

I am currently using `\mathrel{-\!-}` and have difficulty
figuring out the length of the line.

Comment: PS. A detexify search does not give me useful result.

Comment: If possible, can you post the image of the symbol what you want exactly...

Comment: ... there's no real `\longto` in TeX, is there? Only `longrightarrow`

Comment: See also: [symbols - A longer dash like the line from rightarrow without an arrow tip - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433394/a-longer-dash-like-the-line-from-rightarrow-without-an-arrow-tip) (... in both cases the solution relies on the exact width of the arrow...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one ignore the broken `\longmapsto` length under `\scriptscriptstyle`, this should do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\longdash}{}{%
  \mathrel{\relbar\mkern-6.5mu\relbar\mkern-6.5mu\relbar}}

\begin{document}

$a \longmapsto b_{a \longmapsto b_{a \longmapsto b}}$

$a \longdash b_{a \longdash b_{a \longdash b}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The overlap of the backing seems to be unfixable [\xrightarrow has imprecisions in the horizontal part of the arrow - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624320/xrightarrow-has-imprecisions-in-the-horizontal-part-of-the-arrow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you. I think I have never put those in subscript so let me pretend it's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that also avoids the hole in `\scriptscriptstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longdash}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\longvdash@\relax}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longvdash}{\mapstochar\longdash}
\newcommand{\longvdash@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\longrightarrow$}%
  \hb@xt@\wd\z@{\dashfill{#1}}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\dashfill}[1]{% modelled on \rightarrowfill
  $\m@th#1%
  \smash-\mkern-7mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$#1\mkern-2mu\smash-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu\smash-$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \longrightarrow b_{a \longrightarrow b_{a \longrightarrow b}}$

$a \longmapsto b_{a \longmapsto b_{a \longmapsto b}}$

$a \longdash b_{a \longdash b_{a \longdash b}}$

$a \longvdash b_{a \longvdash b_{a \longvdash b}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. `\dashfill` is clever.